# Getting 404 error in the console even though the page is loading

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-404

[image: Failed to load resource: the server responsded with a status of 404 ()]

I am new to AngularJS and keep getting this error in the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responsded with a status of 404 ()

even though the page has loaded.

---

This is the routing I am using

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: "loginController"
    })
    .when("/login", {
        templateUrl: "login.html",
        controller: "loginController"
    }).
    when("/dashboard", {
        templateUrl: "dashboard.html",
        controller: "dashboardController"
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });

$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: true
});
```

For page redirection I am using

```
$location.path('/dashboard');
```

`<base href="/">` is also added.

**Note**: I do not see this error in Incognito Mode.
Why is this error shown and how to correct it?

Comment: Try using `this.$router.navigate(['dashboard'])`

Comment: Not seeing the error in incognito mode suggests something has cached.. have you tried clearing your cache and hard reloading?

Comment: @Michael Yes I have tried that many times